# Подскажите почему выкидывает ошибку System.NullReferenceException: в данном коде

Tags: c#, ооп

Подскжите почему выкидывает ошибку System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' PupilsList was null.
Как исправить. Хочу просто методом AddPupils добавлять в лист обьекты(pupils).

```
 class Pupils
{
    public string name;
    private int age;

    public Pupils()
    {

    }
    public Pupils(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age; 
    }
}

 class MyClass
{

    private List<Pupils> PupilsList;

    public void AddPupil(Pupils pupil)
    {
        
        PupilsList.Add(pupil);

    }

    public void PrintClass(List<Pupils>PupilsList)
    {
        foreach(Pupils pupil in PupilsList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pupil);
        }
    }      
}

 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pupils pupil = new Pupils("Vlad", 24);

        MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

        myclass.AddPupil(pupil);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первая ошибка здесь `private List<Pupils> PupilsList;` ты объявил список но его не инициализировал, то есть у тебя просто в памяти где-то лежит этот список, но ты с ним ничего сделать не сможешь. Заменяем эту строку на эту `private List<Pupils> PupilsList = new List<Pupils>()`

Вторая ошибка в методе `public void PrintClass(List<Pupils>PupilsList)` ты параметром передаешь список и далее в цикле по нему итерируешься, но суть в том что это не тот список который ты ранее объявил. Это вообще какой-то другой список. То есть в методе `public void AddPupil(Pupils pupil)` ты все правильно сделал, ты обращаешься к списку, который ты объявил в этом классе.
Меняем эту строку на эту `public void PrintClass()`

Еще я добавил метод `ToString()` в класс Pupils, чтобы вывод человеческий был.
И еще посмотри пару роликов про чистый код, так никто не называет классы. И отмазка по типу это тестовая прога не прокатит, прививай привычку с самого начала.

```
class Pupil
{
    private string name;
    private int age;

    public Pupil()
    {

    }
    public Pupil(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name + " " + age;
    }
}

class Pupils
{

    private List<Pupil> PupilsList = new List<Pupil>();

    public void AddPupil(Pupil pupil)
    {
        PupilsList.Add(pupil);
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        foreach (Pupil pupil in PupilsList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pupil.ToString());
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pupil pupil = new Pupil("Vlad", 24);
        Pupils pupils = new Pupils();
        pupils.AddPupil(pupil);
        pupils.Show();
    }
}
```